# Suggestion to detecting straight lines on a sand plate, python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I am working on a project that requires detecting lines on a plate of sand. The lines are hand-drew by user so that are not exactly "straight" (see photo). And because of the sand, the lines are quite hard to distinguish. 
[image]

I tried cv2.HoughLines from OpenCV but didn't achieve good results. So any suggestion on the detecting method? And welcome for suggestion to improve the clarity of the lines. I am thinking of putting a few led light surrounding the plate.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The detecting method depends a lot on how much generality you require: is the exposure and contrast going to change from one image to another? Is the typical width of lines going to change? In the following, I assume that such parameters do not vary much for your applications, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I'll be using scikit-image, a common image processing package for Python. If you're not familiar with this package, documentation can be found on http://scikit-image.org/, and the package is bundled with all installations of Scientific Python. However, the algorithms that I use are also available in other tools, like opencv.

My solution is written below. Basically, the principle is

- first, denoise the image. Life is usually simpler after a denoising step. Here I use a total variation filter, since it results in a piecewise-constant image that will be easier to threshold. I enhance dark regions using a morphological erosion (on the gray-level image).
- then apply an adaptive threshold that varies locally in space, since the contrast varies through the image. This operation results in a binary image.
- erode the binary image to break spurious links between regions, and keep only large regions.
- compute a measure of the elongation of the regions to keep only the most elongated ones. Here I use the ratio of the eigenvalues of the inertia tensor.

Parameters that are the most difficult to tune is the block size for the adaptive thresholding, and the minimum size of regions to keep. I also tried a Canny filter on the denoised image (skimage.filters.canny), and results were quite good, but edges were not always closed, you might also want to try an edge-detection method such as a Canny filter.

The result is shown below:
[image: result image]

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, measure, morphology, restoration, filters
from skimage import img_as_float
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open the image
im = io.imread('sand_lines.png')
im = img_as_float(im)

# Denoising
tv = restoration.denoise_tv_chambolle(im, weight=0.4)
ero = morphology.erosion(tv, morphology.disk(5))

# Threshold the image
binary = filters.threshold_adaptive(ero, 181)

# Clean the binary image
binary = morphology.binary_dilation(binary, morphology.disk(8))
clean = morphology.remove_small_objects(np.logical_not(binary), 4000)
labels = measure.label(clean, background=0) + 1

# Keep only elongated regions
props = measure.regionprops(labels)
eigvals = np.array([prop.inertia_tensor_eigvals for prop in props])
eigvals_ratio = eigvals[:, 1] / eigvals[:, 0]
eigvals_ratio = np.concatenate(([0], eigvals_ratio))
color_regions = eigvals_ratio[labels]

# Plot the result
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(color_regions, cmap='spectral')
```